# How to deploy Struts2 application in remote server

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

I have developed a java web application using Struts2 in eclipse. I run the application by using this url

```
http://localhost:8080/newApp
```

application run on the local machine in tomcat server, but I want to run it on a remote server using a url something like this.

```
http://myapp.com/newApp
```

How to do this deployment? What is the server requirements to do this and any tutorial would be appreciated. I want the application to be in a remote server so that remote clients can access the application.

Comment: When you ask about server requirements do you mean hardware requirements? Some people think about software when they hear the word server; as in Apache HTTP Web Server, Domain Name Server. Sometimes when people say server they refer to the hardware on which OS and Servers run. Which are you asking about here? If you are asking about hardware they it is useful to make that clear by referring to the machine where you want to deploy your app as the host or machine or hardware.

Comment: I mean what software should run on the remote server to deploy my application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your local server then download a web server e.g. [**Apache HTTP Server**](http://httpd.apache.org/). Install and configure a [**Virtual Host**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) as `myapp.com` to map `localhost:8080` server.  Once done, you can access your application using `http://myapp.com/newApp` URL. This way, you are still accessing your application locally.

If you want your application to be accessible from **anywhere on the Internet**, you need to have a similar server (I guess you are using `WebLogic`) available on the Internet connected server and you may get `DNS` alias created for the naming of the URL. There are several service provider in the industry, who provide application hosting services with/without some fee. You may want to evaludae that as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: how to deploy struts2 application in remote server?

A: The specifics of deploying an application depend entirely on what kind of server you're using.  Here is an example for WebSphere:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0401_hanis/hanis.html

And here is an example for JBoss:

- http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web-server/jboss-struts-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can use jboss to deploy your application [Jboss Web Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/host.html)

Answer (score 0):

The act of deploying a Struts application will necessitate that you can transfer you application across to it so you will need `sftp` and `ssh` running on the remote machine.

Then you will need the application server of your choice running there; candidates servers would include Tomcat, JBoss, Weblogic from Oracle WebSphere from IBM.

If you want to practice deployment you could make use of VirtualBox and Vagrant to create a Virtual Machine on a local PC where you can install the application servers that you decide upon and practise deploying your app.